# creating a table of last non-NA values that only stores last non-NA values

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

i am having trouble extracting some information from some data i'm working with. i want to extract the last non-NA values for each `id` in each `year` and collect these results in a table which links those values with their original `id` and `year` values.

here is what my data looks like.

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(rep('a', 5), rep('b', 5), rep('c', 5)),
+                   year = c(seq(2011, 2015), seq(2011, 2015), seq(2011, 2015)),
+                   x = c(c(1:3, NA, NA), c(1:5), rep(NA, 5)),
+                   y = c(c(NA, NA, 3, 4, NA), c(NA, 2, 3, 4, NA), rep(NA, 5)),
+                   z = c(c(1:5), c(1:4, NA), rep(NA, 5)))
> 
> dat
   id year  x  y  z
1   a 2011  1 NA  1
2   a 2012  2 NA  2
3   a 2013  3  3  3
4   a 2014 NA  4  4
5   a 2015 NA NA  5
6   b 2011  1 NA  1
7   b 2012  2  2  2
8   b 2013  3  3  3
9   b 2014  4  4  4
10  b 2015  5 NA NA
11  c 2011 NA NA NA
12  c 2012 NA NA NA
13  c 2013 NA NA NA
14  c 2014 NA NA NA
15  c 2015 NA NA NA
```

here is what my ideal result looks like. i did this by hand. if an `id`/`year` pair has a non-NA value for `x`, `y` or `z` but that is not the last value by year, then i want it to be NA.

for example, `a` has non-NA values for `z` in all years, so its last `z` value is `5` and in column `z` of the result table, i want NA for all years except that year for `a`.

```
> target_result <- data.frame(id = c(rep('a', 3), rep('b', 3)),
+                            year = c(2013, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2014, 2014),
+                            last_x = c(3, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA),
+                            last_y = c(NA, 4, NA, NA, 4, NA),
+                            last_z = c(NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, 4))
> 
> target_result
  id year last_x last_y last_z
1  a 2013      3     NA     NA
2  a 2014     NA      4     NA
3  a 2015     NA     NA      5
4  b 2015      5     NA     NA
5  b 2014     NA      4     NA
6  b 2014     NA     NA      4
```

this is my analytical process so far. i think my first step seems okay. i should clarify that the real data i'm working with has daily frequency. i kept my example data small for the sake of simplicity.

```
> step_1 <- dat %>%
+   group_by(id, year) %>%
+   summarize(last_x = last(x),
+             last_y = last(y),
+             last_z = last(z))
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'id'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
> 
> step_1
# A tibble: 15 x 5
# Groups:   id [3]
   id     year last_x last_y last_z
   <chr> <int>  <int>  <dbl>  <int>
 1 a      2011      1     NA      1
 2 a      2012      2     NA      2
 3 a      2013      3      3      3
 4 a      2014     NA      4      4
 5 a      2015     NA     NA      5
 6 b      2011      1     NA      1
 7 b      2012      2      2      2
 8 b      2013      3      3      3
 9 b      2014      4      4      4
10 b      2015      5     NA     NA
11 c      2011     NA     NA     NA
12 c      2012     NA     NA     NA
13 c      2013     NA     NA     NA
14 c      2014     NA     NA     NA
15 c      2015     NA     NA     NA
```

second step also seems okay. some of the rows from my ideal result are in here.

```
> step_2 <- step_1[rowSums(is.na(step_1[,3:5])) < 3,]
> step_2
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   id [2]
   id     year last_x last_y last_z
   <chr> <int>  <int>  <dbl>  <int>
 1 a      2011      1     NA      1
 2 a      2012      2     NA      2
 3 a      2013      3      3      3
 4 a      2014     NA      4      4
 5 a      2015     NA     NA      5
 6 b      2011      1     NA      1
 7 b      2012      2      2      2
 8 b      2013      3      3      3
 9 b      2014      4      4      4
10 b      2015      5     NA     NA
```

but i know that my third step is wrong because it destroys the relationship between the `last_` columns and `year` and just collapses everything into a table that doesn't contain any NA values.

```
> small_and_wrong <- as.data.frame(as.data.table(step_2)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) last(na.omit(x))), id])
> small_and_wrong
  id year last_x last_y last_z
1  a 2015      3      4      5
2  b 2015      5      4      4
```

any advice for how to get back on track? thank you in advance.

Comment: Your target_result seems to have a typo i.e. 'year' 2014 is repeated for id b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe such a solution will be useful

**tidyverse**

```r
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(rep('a', 5), rep('b', 5), rep('c', 5)),
  year = c(seq(2011, 2015), seq(2011, 2015), seq(2011, 2015)),
  x = c(c(1:3, NA, NA), c(1:5), rep(NA, 5)),
  y = c(c(NA, NA, 3, 4, NA), c(NA, 2, 3, 4, NA), rep(NA, 5)),
  z = c(c(1:5), c(1:4, NA), rep(NA, 5))
)

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(id, year), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(id, name) %>% 
  slice_tail(n = 1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, year), names_from = name, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   id     year     x     y     z
#>   <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a      2013     3    NA    NA
#> 2 a      2014    NA     4    NA
#> 3 a      2015    NA    NA     5
#> 4 b      2015     5    NA    NA
#> 5 b      2014    NA     4     4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**data.table**

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

melt(data = setDT(df), id.vars = c("id", "year"), na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  .[order(id, year), last(.SD), by = list(id, variable)] %>% 
  dcast(formula = id + year ~ variable)

#>    id year  x  y  z
#> 1:  a 2013  3 NA NA
#> 2:  a 2014 NA  4 NA
#> 3:  a 2015 NA NA  5
#> 4:  b 2014 NA  4  4
#> 5:  b 2015  5 NA NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: fantastic solution! spasiba, yuriy!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(across(x:z, ~ replace(.x, 
      row_number() < if(any(!is.na(.x))) max(which(!is.na(.x))) 
         else n(), NA))) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   filter(if_any(x:z, ~ !is.na(.x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

By considering max values for non NA values for each column and then applying a condition between year and newly created max column values.

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(rep('a', 5), rep('b', 5), rep('c', 5)), 
                  year = c(seq(2011, 2015), seq(2011, 2015), seq(2011, 2015)), 
                  x = c(c(1:3, NA, NA), c(1:5), rep(NA, 5)), 
                  y = c(c(NA, NA, 3, 4, NA), c(NA, 2, 3, 4, NA), rep(NA, 5)), 
                  z = c(c(1:5), c(1:4, NA), rep(NA, 5)))

library(data.table)

setDT(dat)
```

Creating columns which contains the max year for non NA values based on each column x, y and z grouped by id

```
dat[!is.na(x),':='(Max_YearX = max(year)), by = .(id)]
dat[!is.na(y),':='(Max_YearY = max(year)), by = .(id)]
dat[!is.na(z),':='(Max_YearZ = max(year)), by = .(id)]
```

Changing all the values to NA wherever year is not same.

```
dat[,':='(x = ifelse(Max_YearX != year, NA, x), 
          y = ifelse(Max_YearY != year, NA, y), 
          z = ifelse(Max_YearZ != year, NA, z))]
```

Keeping only the required columns

```
dat <- dat[,.(id, year, x, y, z)]

dat

    id year  x  y  z
 1:  a 2011 NA NA NA
 2:  a 2012 NA NA NA
 3:  a 2013  3 NA NA
 4:  a 2014 NA  4 NA
 5:  a 2015 NA NA  5
 6:  b 2011 NA NA NA
 7:  b 2012 NA NA NA
 8:  b 2013 NA NA NA
 9:  b 2014 NA  4  4
10:  b 2015  5 NA NA
11:  c 2011 NA NA NA
12:  c 2012 NA NA NA
13:  c 2013 NA NA NA
14:  c 2014 NA NA NA
15:  c 2015 NA NA NA
```